# How to listen to command line and 2 incoming connections at the same time

Tags: java, network-programming

I need to create a circular dht in java, and my peer needs to do the following things concurrently -

1. Listen for command line input
2. Listen for a TCP and UDP connection on port X.

Since both listening to the command line and waiting for a connection are blocking tasks, how would I accomplish this? (Since theoretically two threads cannot run at the same time).

Comment: They don't have to "run at the same time". Just use three threads.

Comment: @laune but how will that work? Since threads can not run at the same time, isn't there a possibility of missing connections? Also, I thought doing something like a readline() is blocking, won't that break things?

Comment: Your Java program code doesn't have to catch the bits right at the ethernet connector. Your operating system will take care of that and buffer the data. Blocking on a readline isn't any different from a blocking read on a socket. As I wrote: one thread per socket and stdin = 3 threads.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it. My solution involved using threads.
I used java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService to create the threads, and inside each thread I stated had my server listening to ports.

Comment: You 'figured out' nothing. You were told exactly that last October.